# Cannot click on specified element on UI-Windows Tree using G1ANT Robot

Tags: automation, robotics, rpa, g1ant

I'm trying to use UI addon command-click. After looking for an element in windows tree I decided to use that tool to choose a specific button, which opens in the dialog window on my desktop application. Unfortunately, it wasn't working in the main script -> sometimes it clicked, but not on the button itself, it chose the point outside of the dialog box. The tricky part is that line worked, but in different robot file, I placed only one line, exactly the same and it used to work. Today none of the above works...

> The error it's giving me sounds like this: "Access denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)" do somebody knows how to make it work properly?

I tried switching on/off addons, focusing on different windows, different delays, changing scaling from windows side, etc.

The line I'm using: ui.click wpath "path to element from UI tree"
Also, res. of the screen is 1920x1080p

I can use image recognition on that part of my script, but if it's in the UI windows tree it should work correctly right?

Answer (score 2):

The path could change, check whether you use any properties that could be dynamic (like @id). Consider using `keyboard` command if the button is focusable or has assigned a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: It is updated correctly, state of the application is not changing dynamically. Button might be focusable, but i wanted to use that option to avoid using commands like: mouse.position, keyboard, click etc.